# When submitting forms on the web, you often click a button label 'submit'. I was wondering how to express the word 'submit' in chinese

Tags: translation

At the bottom of a web form, you might click update, or submit. I was wondering what the Chinese word for 'submit' is, and if this is correct: 提交. Similarly, if there is a distinct word for 'update'.

Comment: Yes. Update is `更新`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are 提交 and 更新, respectively. FYI, I am a native speaker with enough knowledge of IT terminology.

Answer (score 2):

In mainland China,
submit - 提交
update - 更新
clear  - 清空

I'm not sure if they are used in Hongkong or Taiwan.

Answer (score 2):

For "submit", you can use:

1)提交

If that's a file to be posted onto a server, please use:

2)上传

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "submit" means "提交", and "update" means "更新". But I couldn't find "update" button in Twitter, Amazon and Linkedin. So that I couldn't take a screenshot.
[image]